# How to fix m2eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have java maven project in Eclipse that depends from other projects and for near 1000 library jar.
But I cannot use m2eclipse at all. 
For create Eclipse project is use eclipse maven plugin like:

```
 mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=1.5
```

It works well. But when I go to Eclipse and click on m2eclipe - update dependencies - all library jars disappear!
So for work I have disabled java projects as maven in Eclipse. I suppose that there is some problem with eclipse internal variables. Does it correct? What have I check? Does exist some log? Or this is common bug of m2eclipse plugin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) (i.e. mvn eclipse:eclipse) no longer works with [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) or its current version, [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/).

Assuming you have the latest Eclipse (Indigo, which comes with m2e), you should have better success opening the maven project directly (Import as Maven project).

Comment: Problem not in maven eclipse plugin. It works well. Problem in m2e - that destroy the project.